# Peak finding algorithm - Dynamic thresholding or alternative methods

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing, threshold

I'm looking for some advice. Sorry if this, or you feel belongs on an alternative site.

I've been tasked with identifying specific social calls (from bats) within a signal, and I've been playing around with the types of methods that I should use in order to isolate the different calls. So, to start off with, this is what the signal looks like as a whole:

[image]

This signal is very large, and thus the signal is split into blocks, of `1024*100` (roughly around 10MB each) and here is a sample of a block:

[image]

This signal is more desirable, and the peaks, visually can easily be identified. Here are some questions regarding this:

1) Would calculating the Short-term energy be an adequate method for determining the peaks?

2) Is there a method to dynamically assign the threshold value? E.g. the algorithm created for this block, should potentially work for all other blocks within the signal and any other signal inputted?

3) Would converting this signal to the frequency domain (using STFT methods) make any difference?

Here is the block using the FFT algorithm:

[image]

The expected output:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm just curious: Is it not possible to filter these signals with 101 statistics ...

Comment: @achingfingers I'm not aware of the concept? If you mean the programming language, I'm using C++/Python in order to solve this problem.. Why would using 101 statistics make a difference, just out of curiosity?

Comment: I didn't want to be offensive. And I am not really into what you are doing ... but to me the above pattern looks like it could be easily filtered with a standard deviation threshold ... implemented in your language of choice of course.

Comment: @achingfingers Oh, my apologies if my response came across as if I was taking offence, I'm really not (just stressed!!). Thank you for your reply :) I'll look up standard deviation thresholding and see where that get's me, I was just unaware of the concept that's all! I'll post back!

Comment: @achingfingers Sorry, do you have any papers or tutorials that might be useful on standard deviation thresholding? Would be helpful :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Comment: @achingfingers Oh. So basically, find the Standard Deviation and then this is then the threshold value for the signal?

Comment: Yes. It's just a quick suggestion without really knowing what you do .... but you could look where your signal "enters" a region outside , let's say 3 sigma, and where it "returns" next. Then find the maximum value within that range (which is your local maximum then)

Comment: Even though your problem with bat calls is from a totaly different field, maybe it is compareable to what is called _onset detection_ in music processing: Finding time points where note events begin. If his is interesting for you: [A Tutorial on Onset Detection in Music Signals (J. P. Bello, L. Daudet, S. Abdallah, C. Duxbury, M. Davies, and M. B. Sandler)](http://icdif.com/soundit/Bello-TSAP-2005.pdf)

Comment: Are the axis correctly labeled in the FFT?  Is it not frequency vs magnitude?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Oops, that's embarrassing sorry - Just noticed that

Comment: Have you tried findpeaks?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.  You have to experiment to find out the proper interval length.
2. Yes.  One way would be to start with the average energy of a larger block, and set the threshold like 10 times of that.
3. Depends.  Do you want to know the frequency?  It could be used to distinguish bat-noises from unrelated types of background noise.  If there isn't a lot of other noise and you are not interested in the frequency, don't bother.  It doesn't help if you just want to find the peaks.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably papers on peak detection algorithm. But if you don't have time, you can try to move along a time-window and use its energy to calculate a treshold.

Perhaps you can also look into the peak density (if there is more or less the same number of peaks along the time) to know how many peak you should expect to find into a given window. (Well, if there is no silence, but it's usually easy to differentiate silence from noise using the energy).

I doubt FFT would help. There is no significant frequency from what we can see, and any kind of filtering would pollute the peaks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the frequencies,  check out time-frequency analysis. Perhaps a wavelet or wigner transform could help,  or a simple sonogram.

Time–frequency representations usually give you time,  energy and frequency all at once.  Good stuff.